# How to mark a in pyparsing position in stream to come back to it later?

Tags: html, markup, pyparsing

Background:

I am trying to implement a simple (?) markup language to be used to write novels.

This is quite different from usual markups because semantic is centered on different primitives, in particular direct speech is far from being similar to a list.

The basic structure is well-known: `@part{title}`, `@chapter{title}` and `@scene[{title}]` have the usual meanings and double-`\n` indicates a paragraph break.

Specific features include:

- @speach[speaker]{utterance, possibly complex}
- @stress{something that should be visually enhanced}
- @standout{some part that should have a different visual enhancement}
- @quotation[original author]{possibly long block quotation}

This should be parsed and translated to different output formats (e.g.: html and LaTeX).

I have a `pyparsing` grammar able to parse a non-trivial input.

Problem is generation of paragraphs for HTML:

As said a paragraph ends with double-newline, but essentially starts from end of previous paragraph unless some top-level constucts (e.g.: `@chapter`) intervene to break sequence.

First naive attempt was to accumulate text fragments in a global buffer and to emit them at selected points; this wold logically work, but it seems `pyparsing` calls it's `ParseActions` multiple times, so my global buffer ends up holding the same fragment duplicated.

I have not found a way to either avoid such duplication or to mark the "start of paragraph" in such a way I can come back to it later to generate the well-known `<p>Long line, maybe containing @speech{possibly nested with @standout{!} and other constructs}</p>` (of course `@standout` should map to `<b>!</b>` and`@speech` to some specific `<div class="speech"></div>`)

What is the "best practice" to handle this kind of problems?

Note: LaTeX code generation is much less problematic because paragraphs are simply terminated (like in the markup) either with a blank line or with `\par`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you recast this not as a "come back to the beginning later" problem but as a "read ahead as far as I need to get the whole thing" problem?

I think `nestedExpr` might be a way for you to read ahead to the next full markup, and then have a parse action re-parse the contents in order to process any nested markup directives. `nestedExpr` returns its parsed input as a nested list, but to get everything as a flattened string, wrap it in `originalTextFor`.

Here is a rework of the simpleWiki.py example from the pyparsing examples:

```
import pyparsing as pp

wiki_markup = pp.Forward()

# a method that will construct and return a parse action that will
# do the proper wrapping in opening and closing HTML, and recursively call 
# wiki_markup.transformString on the markup body text
def convert_markup_to_html(opening,closing):
    def conversionParseAction(s, l, t):
        return opening + wiki_markup.transformString(t[1][1:-1]) + closing
    return conversionParseAction

# use a nestedExpr with originalTextFor to parse nested braces, but return the 
# parsed text as a single string containing the outermost nested braces instead
# of a nested list of parsed tokens
markup_body = pp.originalTextFor(pp.nestedExpr('{', '}'))
italicized = ('ital' + markup_body).setParseAction(convert_markup_to_html("<I>", "</I>"))
bolded = ('bold' + markup_body).setParseAction(convert_markup_to_html("<B>", "</B>"))

# another markup and parse action to parse links - again using transform string
# to recursively parse any markup in the link text
def convert_link_to_html(s, l, t):
    t['link_text'] = wiki_markup.transformString(t['link_text'])
    return '<A href="{url}">{link_text}</A>'.format_map(t)
urlRef = ('link' 
          + '{' + pp.SkipTo('->')('link_text') + '->' + pp.SkipTo('}')('url') + '}'
          ).setParseAction(convert_link_to_html)

# now inject all the markup bits as possible markup expressions
wiki_markup <<= urlRef | italicized | bolded
```

Try it out!

```
wiki_input = """
Here is a simple Wiki input:

  ital{This is in italics}.
  bold{This is in bold}!
  bold{This is in ital{bold italics}! But this is just bold.}
  Here's a URL to link{Pyparsing's bold{Wiki Page}!->https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/wiki}
"""
print(wiki_markup.transformString(wiki_input))
```

Prints:

```
Here is a simple Wiki input:

  <I>This is in italics</I>.
  <B>This is in bold</B>!
  <B>This is in <I>bold italics</I>! But this is just bold.</B>
  Here's a URL to <A href="https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/wiki">Pyparsing's <B>Wiki Page</B>!</A>
```

Given your markup examples, I think this approach may get you further along.